# recursive to iterative return equivalent?

Tags: c++

assume this random code which is looks similar to the technique of working i am concerned with in this question:

```
int randomNumber(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return 3;
    int c1 = 1+randomNumber(n-2);
    int c2 = 2 + randomNumber(n-1);
    return c1 + c2;
}
```

i want to convert it to iterative form, every call is equivalent to pushing something to an explicit stack, but every return statement which will return something to its caller, what is it equivalent to ? i thought of saving the location in the stack after every call and return to it again after the return statement but this seems to be not possible.

EDIT: to make myself more clear, consider this more complex random example:

```
int pal(string s, int i) {
    if (i > s.length()/2) {
        return 0;
    }
    string s1 = s, s2 = s;
    int c1, c2;
    if (s1[i] == s1[i + 1]) {
        s1.insert(i + 1, "a");
        c1 = 1 + pal(s1, i + 1);
    }
    else {
        c1 = pal(s1, i + 1);
    }
    if (s2[i] == s2[i + 2]) {
        s2.insert(i + 2, "b");
        c2 = 1 + pal(s2, i + 1);
    }
    else {
        c2 = pal(s2, i + 1);
    }
    return c1 > c2 ? c1 : c2;
}
```

i don't think it will be converted to iterative form by the same simplicity

EDIT2: my question is originally because i want to minimize the time for such functions, for example the last previous example i want to minimize its time for large strings (it takes nearly forever to compute the result for large strings for a program like the previous one)

Comment: I guess you should learn dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost Fibonacci:

```
n = -1, r = 3
n = 0, r = 3
n = 1, r = 9 (1+3 + 2+3)
n = 2, r = 15 (1+3 + 2+9)
n = 3, r = 27 (1+9 + 2+15)
n = 4, r = 45 (1+15 + 2+27)
n = 5, r = 75 (1+27 + 2+45)
. . .
```

So you can use simple iterative algorithm to calculate the series:

```
int randomNumer(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 3;

    a = 3;
    b = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int t = a;
        a = b;
        b = (1 + t) + (2 + a);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is a [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) one (i.e. no side-effects), you can use [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), or caching. That is, make a mapping of input to output, and use it first when calculating your function.

```
int randomNumber_with_memo(int n, std::map<int, int>& memo)
{
    int& result = memo[n]; // find precalculated result; if not found, use 0
    if (result == 0) // not found
    {
        int c1 = 1+randomNumber_with_memo(n-2, memo);
        int c2 = 2 + randomNumber_with_memo(n-1, memo);
        result = c1 + c2; // this also updates the memo
    }
    return result;
}

int randomNumber(int n) {
    std::map<int, int> memo;
    memo[-2] = 3;
    memo[-1] = 3;
    memo[0] = 3;
    return randomNumber_with_memo(n, memo);
}
```

This is mostly a hack:

- It doesn't attempt to reuse the memo between different invocations of `randomNumber`
- It uses a `map` instead of a more efficient `vector` (or array)
- It relies on 0 as a sentinel value - it should never be a valid result

But it has one advantage - you don't have to analyze your code. Just wrap it with a memoization function, and it will probably work faster.

Note: this doesn't attempt to convert recursion to iteration.

Answer (score 0):

for time to be minimized you may use linked list instead of string because of many insertions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
int pal2(std::list<char>& s, decltype(declval<std::list<char>>().begin())  it , int i)
{
    if (i > s.size()/2) {
    return 0;
    }
    int c1, c2;
    auto next = std::next (it ,1);
    if(*it == *next)
    {
    s.insert(next, 'a');
    c1 = 1 + pal2(s,std::next (it ,1), i + 1);
    s.erase(std::next (it ,1));
    }
    else{
    c1 = pal2(s, std::next (it ,1), i + 1);
    }
    next = std::next (it ,2);
    if (*it == *next) {
    s.insert(next, 'b');
    c2 = 1 + pal2(s,std::next (it ,1), i + 1);
    s.erase(std::next (it ,2));
    }
    else {
    c2 = pal2(s,std::next (it ,1), i + 1);
    }
    return c1 > c2 ? c1 : c2;
}
int main()
{
    auto test = std::string("sssaaaasbbbabaaaaam");
    std::list<char> s(test.begin(),test.end());
    int i = 4;
    std::cout << pal2(s, std::next(std::begin(s),i),i);
}
```